# bootstrap 3 modal breaking on AJAX response - mvc4

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation, bootstrap-modal

My `bootstrap modal footer` just doesn't show up.

Main View

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalId">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button"  data-dismiss="modal">Log</button>                  
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="form">
                    <div id="ModalBodyId">    
                        @Html.Partial("PartialViewName");
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer"> // this part doesn't show up
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="SaveNow()";>Edit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is what loads the partial view into the modal. I had to add the below code for the validation to work. The validation works fine now, however i do not see the `button` which is contained inside the modal  footer.

```
$("#ModalId").click(function () {
    var form = $("#ModalBodyId").closest("form");
    form.removeData('validator');
    form.removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);

    $.ajax({
        url: "/ControllerName/ActionName",
        type: "GET",
        data: $("#ModalBodyId").serialize(),
        cache: false
    });


});
```

> If i remove the `@Html.Partial("PartialViewName");` from modal-body then the modal-footer shows up.

Comment: The `onclick` attribute of the button is not closing properly. Maybe its not showing because of this?

Comment: @TasosK. that was my miss in the question...that is not why it is missing

Comment: Then I guess it is a CSS issue. Have tried inspecting the `<div>` with the browser's dev tools? T

Comment: @TasosK....yes did that...modal footer is just not present in the rendered html...if i remove the Html.Partial line then the footer shows up.

Comment: Does the partial have an extra div?

Comment: Maybe the ajax response has broken html

Comment: partial view is contained in `<div class="row">`

Comment: @TasosK....how can this be fixed. if i move the button inside the modal header then it shows up

Comment: any help would be appreciated

Comment: What does the partial view look like? To help debug this try reducing the partial view to a empty div -- is it still broken? This will help you narrow down the problem.